# Reducing Duplicate Javascript Code for Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing this question because I have an AJAX request for deleting posts into my website that is working fine but I have duplicated it multiple times to match the URL for different Custom Post Type that I have in the page.

Here the original code:

```
jQuery(".delete-listing-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    var thisPost = jQuery(e.target).parents(".agent-dashboard-listing-card")
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', msSiteData.nonce);
        }, 
        url: 'https://mallorca-select.com/wp-json/wp/v2/properties-for-sale/' + thisPost.data('id'),
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function () {
            alert(" Listing Deleted Successfully! ");
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

In these functions the only thing that changes is a part of the URL request like this:

'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/**post-type-1**/' + thisPost.data('id')

'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/**post-type-2**/' + thisPost.data('id')

'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/**post-type-3**/' + thisPost.data('id')

'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/**post-type-4**/' + thisPost.data('id')

**I'm wondering if there is a method for detecting the post type of the post where the delete button is clicked and inject inside the URL request so I don't have to duplicate it 4 times only to change the custom post type inside the url.**

Answer (score 2):

Move the common AJAX code to a separate function and pass the specific URL you need in each case.

```
jQuery(".delete-listing-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    var thisPost = jQuery(e.target).parents(".agent-dashboard-listing-card")
    
    sendRequest('properties-for-sale');
});

const sendRequest = (requestUrl) => {
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', msSiteData.nonce);
        }, 
        url: `https://mallorca-select.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${requestUrl}/${thisPost.data('id')}`,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function () {
            alert(" Listing Deleted Successfully! ");
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can use another `data` attribute to hold the post type URL route - as you already are for the `id`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".delete-listing-btn").on("click", e => {
    let $button = $(e.target);
    let $thisPost = $button.parents(".agent-dashboard-listing-card");
    let url = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/${$button.data('post-type')}/${$button.data('id')}`;

    console.log(url);

    // your AJAX request here...
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="delete-listing-btn" data-post-type="post-type-1" data-id="1">Post Type 1</button>
<button class="delete-listing-btn" data-post-type="post-type-2" data-id="2">Post Type 2</button>
<button class="delete-listing-btn" data-post-type="post-type-3" data-id="3">Post Type 3</button>
<button class="delete-listing-btn" data-post-type="post-type-4" data-id="4">Post Type 4</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. I think this is the easiest and most efficient way I can do it. The only thing is that inside the ajax request in the url of the request i need to paste the variable "url" right? Like this: "url: url"

Comment: Yes, that's correct.